# Disable a button for a particular tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two tabs:-

```
<div class="modal-body">
   <form name="myForm" novalidate="novalidate">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
       <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#basicInfo">Info</a></li>
       <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#view">View Details</a></li>
    </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
     <div id="basicInfo"  class="tab-pane fade in active modal-table-div">
      .....
     </div>
  <div id="view" class="tab-pane modal-table-div fade">
     .....
     </div>
</div>
```

And a Delete and Add button button:

```
<div class="modal-footer">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Add</button>
</div>
```

What I want is when I click on the 'view details' tab the delete button and add button got disabled and viceversa.How should I achieve that?

Comment: Can we see how you are detecting which tab is clicked ?

Answer (score 4):

I would add a class `diableButton` to the `link` that shall trigger the disable function, use the code below.

This line `$(this).find("a").hasClass("diableButton")` will then ask if our `link` has the class.

```js
$('.nav-tabs li').click(function() {
  if ($(this).find("a").hasClass("diableButton")) {
    $('.modal-footer button').prop("disabled", true);
  } else {
    $('.modal-footer button').prop("disabled", false);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="modal-body">
  <form name="myForm" novalidate="novalidate">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#basicInfo">Info</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" class="diableButton" href="#view">View Details</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
      <div id="basicInfo" class="tab-pane fade in active modal-table-div">
        .....
      </div>
      <div id="view" class="tab-pane modal-table-div fade">
        .....
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Add</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: @shreyagupta Please accept the answer if it's the solution you choose. Is the best way to say thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  var href= $(e.target).attr("href");
  // check href here and do what you want
});
```

and check [Bootstrap JS Tab](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_tab.asp) for all events

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.prop()` method to disable the buttons:

```
var isViewTab = $('.modal-body li.active a').attr('href') === "#view";
$(".modal-body").find(".btn-danger,.btn-success") // get the modal buttons
                .prop('disabled', isViewTab ) // disabled them
                .toggleClass('disabled', isViewTab); // add a class to style them disbled
```